# How do I back out of a backout?

Tags: mercurial, backout

I've recently committed a whole load of files I didn't mean to, and backed out. Realising I've removed all the changes, I updated to the revision with the "committed files" before the backout. But I can re-commit them as changed files.

Is it possible to backout of a backout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have [MqExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) installed, you can simply `hg strip` any commits you don't want, although you should only really do this if you haven't yet pushed them. This is often easier and tidier than trying to commit a series of backouts to get back to where you want to be.

Comment: My biggest mistake was failing to define the files to commit, but a quick dozen things. I also found out you can backout of a backout - and thanks.